# Why does that hamburger menu not work?

Tags: html, css

Can you tell me why that hamburger menu doesnt work? I really didn't find an answer ;( The connection HTML/Javascript is okay. What I must say is that I do not understand Javascript, I just copied the code from the net, maybe there's something wrong with the JavaScript file? All my files are in one folder, no subfolders:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="nav.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Menu</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="#" class="hamburger">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </a>
            <ul class="clearfix menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700');

*, *:before, *:after {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}

html, body {
height: 100%;
}

body {
font: 1em 'Roboto', sans-serif;
color: #555;
background-color: #fff;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

ul {
list-style: none;
max-width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

h1 {
padding: 30px 0;
font: 1.5em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
}

nav {
border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

ul a {
display: block;
padding: 20px;
padding-right: 0 !important; /* important overrides media queries */
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
color: #aaa;
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul a:hover {
background: #eee;
}

nav li {
float: left;
width: 20%;
border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

nav li:last-child {
border-right: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

.hamburger {
    padding: 15px;
    display: block;
}

.line {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #bbb;
    width: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.line:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

nav li {
    width: 100%;
}

.menu {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 0.3s linear;
}

.slide-down {
    height: 262px;
}
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.hamburger').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('.menu').toggleClass('slide-down');
});
```

Comment: have you added `jQuery`? I don't see it. Add it before any other script and it should work.

Comment: i've added it now but it still doesnt work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xg3s83yo/ Its working. Check on small screen

Comment: so the problem lies in the connection of JS and HTML, for me it still doesnt work after puting     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  before all other scripts. Any clue?

Comment: could you please make a fiddle for your code and give me link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make that responsive hamburger menu work? It just doesnt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683972/how-to-make-that-responsive-hamburger-menu-work-it-just-doesnt)

Answer (score 1):

I just copied your code to a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xg3s83yo/), it pretty much works.
You either:

- Forgot to include [jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/#jquery-2-x)
- Forgot to include [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
- You're using IE <= 8

By the way, the burger icon won't show unless you resize your window to a smaller width.

Try adding to your `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Hi. I've already added jQuery, Im using Chrome newest version, but I dont know what you mean by including bootstrap? I tried it with your code but it also doesnt work ;(

Comment: EDIT: Its funny, Ive tried a totally different code for navigation and it also seems to have a problem with the slide function of javascript??

Answer (score -1):

Here is working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/eu3kmc5d/) of your code. 
Try adding jQuery file under `<head>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="nav.js"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: Just edited the post see it carefully i changed the loading sequence first `jQuery' then 'custom-js'

Comment: does that work for you when you test it? i tried but it still doesnt open that menu slide ;(

Comment: Since I don't have `nav.js` I tested on [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eu3kmc5d/) where it's working okay. Make output window smaller and check it.