# How to make that responsive hamburger menu work? It just doesnt

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can you tell me why that hamburger menu doesn't open?

- all the files are in one folder as you can see here:
  [image]
- jQuery is included on first position
- using Chromes newest version

But still it doesn't work ;( If I copy the code on jsfiddle everything works, so I think there is a problem the the connection HTML/JS? Also the funny thing is that if I try out some other different navigation from codepen, it also doesnt open.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Menu</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="#" class="hamburger">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </a>
            <ul class="clearfix menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700');

*, *:before, *:after {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}

html, body {
height: 100%;
}

body {
font: 1em 'Roboto', sans-serif;
color: #555;
background-color: #fff;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

ul {
list-style: none;
max-width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

h1 {
padding: 30px 0;
font: 1.5em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
}

nav {
border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

ul a {
display: block;
padding: 20px;
padding-right: 0 !important; /* important overrides media queries */
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
color: #aaa;
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul a:hover {
background: #eee;
}

nav li {
float: left;
width: 20%;
border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

nav li:last-child {
border-right: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

.hamburger {
    padding: 15px;
    display: block;
}

.line {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #bbb;
    width: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.line:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

nav li {
    width: 100%;
}

.menu {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 0.3s linear;
}

.slide-down {
    height: 262px;
}
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.hamburger').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('.menu').toggleClass('slide-down');
});
```

Comment: Unable to replicate - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/oLjoRX

Comment: You said you couldn't reproduce it in a JS Fiddle.  When running it locally are there errors in your console?  Are you placing your hamburger JS inside a document ready?

Comment: Why post a dupe of your own question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679165/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you run the javascript code only when the document is ready-

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.hamburger').on('click', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('.menu').toggleClass('slide-down');
    });
});
```

Comment: YOU ARE MY MAN! THANKS!